# PSfrag does not change the text

Tags: psfrag

I want to practice `psfrag` but it does not work! I don't know what to do.

Here is my `LaTeX` document,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \psfrag{a}{$x_{n-2}$}\psfrag{b}{$x_{n-1}$}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{edge.eps}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and here is [my edge.eps file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ex9lt9d9e4dyvag/edge.eps?dl=0)

ps. I installed TeX Live last week on [tug.org](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and I use WinEdt 10.1.

ps 2. I'm not familiar to TeX, so I didn't touch any setting in WinEdt. I would appreciate if you would explain what to do.(sorry for bad English)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you use `latex`? It should work, if you use `pdflatex`, there's more to do.

Comment: It works for me out of the box using `latex`. [Output image](http://imgur.com/GUS4VPX) -- in fact, I think this could be easier with `tikz` and directly drawing the graphics

Comment: oh my default setting is `pdflatex` because my friend taught me pdflatex. However, in my image, it remains just as 'a' and 'b'

Comment: See my possible by-pass solution for `pdflatex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psfrag` needs `latex` to compile (due to the `.eps` support).

However, with `auto-pst-pdf` package and the `\includegraphics` wrapper `\psfragfig`, it's possible to use `pdflatex` as well.

Make sure, that `--shell-escape` is enabled!

If `graphicx` is loaded, `graphics` don't needs to be loaded as well (because it's loaded by `graphicx`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \psfrag{a}{$x_{n-2}$}\psfrag{b}{$x_{n-1}$}
%    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{edge.eps}
    \psfragfig[width=5cm]{edge.eps}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Error message occured!   `! Package auto-pst-pdf Error:
"shell escape" (or "write18") is not enable: auto-pst-pdf will not work!`

Comment: Well, yes, I wrote that it must be enabled

Comment: @TaeheeHong: That's fine!